# SQL "Connect By" with a Dynamic Hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to use "connect by" on a table that correlates a head to a tail in a hierarchy by ID (i.e., head_id, tail_id).  This simple query would and does work:

```
select head_id, tail_id  
from links  
start with head_id = :1  
connect by prior tail_id = head_id
```

However, tail_id is not always accurate so I created a function to return the correct tail_id, "get_latest_id(id)".  I would think that this updated query would work:

```
select head_id, tail_id, get_latest_id(tail_id) as latest_tail_id  
from cms_links  
start with head_id = :1  
connect by prior latest_tail_id = head_id;
```

But that throws the error "ORA-00904: "LATEST_TAIL_ID": invalid identifier"

My goal is to relate the parent row's corrected tail_id as head_id in the children rows.  If I understand the Oracle docs correctly, that means that I must use "prior" in the "connect by" clause.

Can my goal be realized with the "connect by"?  If so, what is the correct syntax?

Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated.

Michael

Comment: The CONNECT BY is evaluated before the SELECT so `latest_tail_id` doesn't exist within the scope of the statement... you need to use the function in the CONNECT BY. Having said that, this seems pretty... horrible, especially if the function is at all complicated. If it's incorrect and you can correct it why can't you just correct it in the database and then you can use it more simply.

Comment: Have you tried: connect by prior get_latest_id(tail_id) = head_id;

Comment: P.S. "evaluated" is a bad choice of words; but it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Ben and Roberto - thank you for your quick and correct replies!  Ben - I agree that it is not ideal to have to correct the tail ids, but it is actually a feature of the third party application managing the links table.  It would be complicated to explain why it is that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments, you can't use the column alias of the `select` in the `connect by`. You will need to call the function again in the `connect by`:

```
connect by prior get_latest_id(tail_id) = head_id
```